# Cannot launch Android Emulator visual studio 2019

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2019

After installing windows 10 update whenever launching an android emulator I get

[image]

Could anybody advice what do to? How do you reinstall the sdk,remove it

many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the obvious first - restart the Visual Studio and the PC.

If that doesn't work then try selecting Tools->Android->Android Device Manager and play around from there. Try creating a new instance of a different device. Google Pixel or Nexus for example.
Try different options from there.

Comment: I have also checked haxm hyperventilation  shall I reinstall visual studio seems a bit extreme but I am stuck

Comment: Rebooted - removed all the emulators  unchecked haxm and checked again and worked. Weird stuff going on but working now